# EventLogQuery does not return new event log records

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

I have a task to poll application event log periodically to check for new entries and process them, later parsing them to an .evtx file.

This task is not a problem.
I am using a code like that:

```
using (var els = new EventLogSession())
{
     string timeString = timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
     string queryString = String.Format(
         "<QueryList>  <Query Id='0' Path='{0}'> <Select Path='{0}'> " + 
         "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;'{1}']]]</Select> </Query> </QueryList>",
         logName, timeString);
     var query = new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName, queryString) { Session = els };
     var records = new List<EventRecord>();
     using (var logReader = new EventLogReader(query))
     {
         EventRecord record;
         while ((record = logReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
         {
              //log entries processed here
              ...
              //finally export log messages to a file
              els.ExportLogAndMessages(logName, PathType.LogName, queryString, fileName, true, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
         }
     }
}
```

Unfortunately I found out that after restarting my PC and starting application - EventLogReader always returns the same set of messages, even if I restart my application. That means - new messages do not appear in the results yielded by logReader.ReadEvent() method.

However - changing query string to a simple  asterisk and passing it to EventLogQuery - resolves this situation, logReader returns all messages including new ones.
For now, I stick with "*" query string and filter old entries with code, but this seems to be not the best solution to me.

Is it a mistake in my query? Is it a mistake with my handling of EventLogSession or EventLogReader objects? Is it a known MS bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it doesn't have an answer and I've been working in this area lately.

Possible issues with this code:

Use UTC time for your date, and

```
.ToString("o")
```

instead of

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
```

Don't include any of the extraneous XML in the query string. You only need the query bit. So it should be:

```
 string queryString = String.Format(
     "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;'{0}']]]",
     timeString);
```

Consider using an EventBookmark instead of constructing a complex query expression for date filtering. EventBookmarks were designed for that purpose. See [How to create an EventBookmark when querying the event log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509513/how-to-create-an-eventbookmark-when-querying-the-event-log) for an example of using EventBookmark for a very similar kind of purpose.

Once you have an EventBookmark you simply use:

```
 using (var logReader = new EventLogReader(query, EventBookmark))
```

to ensure that your reader starts at the entry after the previous bookmark.